# Some of the problems in using CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I used data model defines a '**Teacher**', and a '**Student**'.
'Teacher' and 'Student' is one-to-many.

eg:

```
student.whoTeach = teacher
```

I want to use `NSPredicate` to get `NSFetchedResultsController` of 'Student',and those student are the same teacher,then I will show them in `UITableView`.

But I don't know how to get 'the same teacher'.

---

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];  

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]; // This I don't know how to code!

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

---

Comment: request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whoTeach == %@", self.teacher];  // It's right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is right jellysfinsh

you can use the above syntax to get the information of the student related to the teacher by using this syntax

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whoTeach == %@", self.teacher];